# Looping or iterating through a secure web request to retrieve all records from ESRI Feature Service using C#

Tags: c#, loops, webrequest, esri

I am relatively new to C#. I am working on a C# console application to sync data from GIS to a business system. The datasets I am retrieving from GIS are larger than the allowed record set returned from querying the service. Below is my code for retrieving data from the service (URL modified for public display). Is there a way I can loop or iterate through the request to pull all records for the dataset? The code below works to retrieve the first 2000 records of the dataset.

public static string MyData
{

```
        get
        {
            var token = GetToken();
            string result = string.Empty;
            var url = new Uri("https://mydata.com/mapping/rest/services/GeoEvent/MyData/FeatureServer/0/query?where=0%3D0&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=OBJECTID,SIID,COLL_METHOD,COLL_STATUS,COLL_CMTS,CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE,SID&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=4269&having=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=OBJECTID&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&historicMoment=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&queryByDistance=&returnExtentOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&quantizationParameters=&featureEncoding=esriDefault&f=pjson");
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.Host = "mydata.com";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Esri-Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

                         
            Rootobject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(result);
             foreach(Feature featureitem in obj.features)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(featureitem.attributes.OBJECTID + "-" + featureitem.attributes.COLL_STATUS + "-" + featureitem.attributes.CREATED_BY + "-" + featureitem.attributes.CREATED_DATE + "-" + featureitem.attributes.MODIFIED_BY + "-" + featureitem.attributes.COLL_CMTS + "-" + featureitem.attributes.SID + "-" + featureitem.attributes.SIID + "-" + featureitem.geometry.x + "-" + featureitem.geometry.y);
            }
```

Comment: *"the first 2000 records of the dataset"* - What specifically causes it to stop?  When you debug, how many elements are in the `obj.features` collection?

Comment: It reaches the maxAllowedRecords ( "exceededTransferLimit": true) returned from the query. I can manually change the result offset to 2000 to pull the next group of records, but what I would prefer is to loop through the query until I have retrieved all records. For the sake of discussion, the dataset in question has 5000 records.

Comment: If the API operation only returns 2000 records then that's all you can loop through.  It sounds like what you want is to put this entire code snippet into a bigger loop to make multiple queries to the API.  Wherever you specify the records you want from the API query, that's what you'd modify in that loop.

Answer (score 0):

two options:

Query with `returnIdsOnly` = true. This will return all records, but only their object IDs. From there, you can query batches or individuals by Id.

Query with `resultOffset` and `resultRecordCount` values. First query would be:

```
?resultOffset=0&resultRecordCount=1000
```

Next would be:

```
?resultOffset=1000&resultRecordCount=1000
```

etc

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. I know I can do this process manually, but what I would like to do is automate the process so that the app runs (e.g., nightly). Thus there cannot be any user input. What I thought about doing is querying on record count first, and then using this information to determine the parameters and # queries needed to pull data. I am just stuck on linking the queries together so no user intervention is required.

Comment: You can pass those parameters through in your code as well; you don't need to do it interactively. For example, increment the offset until you don't get any results. Also, you may consider using a tool like FME that is purpose built for this kind of task (eg nightly downloading and translating of features from a map service)